# Using Bootstrap & jQuery, how to do I get the container class to change to a smaller size when the sidebar is activated?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have re-posted this question in better form and included more code in my example.  I would delete this one but it says not to delete.

Here's a link to my reposted question...
[Using Bootstrap & jQuery, how to get the container class to change to a smaller size only when the sidebar is BOTH activated and overlapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443190/using-bootstrap-jquery-how-to-get-the-container-class-to-change-to-a-smaller?noredirect=1#comment56628165_34443190)

Answer (score 2):

You need to dynamically adjust container width using javascript/jquery. You can define css class with reduced container rules and attach this class to the container element's class name using jquery on the sidebar expand event.

something like this:

css:

```
.container-resize{
width: 450 px;
}
```

script:

```
function expandSideBar(){

$('.container').addClass('container-resize');//reduce size of container 

}
```

Note: You may need to reduce the width of some elements inside the container also.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just create a new class that sets the new width you want for the container when the sidebar is visible.

for example.

you have

```
.container{
   width: 960px;
}
```

after sidebar becomes active just replace that with
.... if the sidebar width is 160px for example.

```
.new container {
   width: 800px;
   transform: translateX(160px); /*the magic*/     
}
```

and use `transform: translateX(160px); to move the body 160px to the right or left of the screen so the the bar does not cover your content.`

you are already using js. so you should have no issue doing this.