# Using Bootstrap & jQuery, how to get the container class to change to a smaller size only when the sidebar is BOTH activated and overlapping?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout with a hidden sidebar that appears on the right hand side by using .toggleClass from jQuery to toggle *on/off* the sidebar. When the class is toggled *on*(visible), the sidebar appears from the right and the .css rule padding-right:250px; is applied to the #wrapper that has a Bootstrap *container* class.

The *container* class is built-in to the Bootstrap.css that makes the page responsive, so that it resizes based on the browser window width. The way it's currently set, is when the sidebar opens, it may or may not overlap the container, depending on how wide the browser window is at the moment... I can setup a css rule to resize the container and toggle that class *on/off*, but then that doesn't consider that sometimes it does not need to be added. **Only** when there is an overlap because the window isn't wide enough does it need to be added.

#### css:

```
#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-right: 250px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

#### script:

```
$("#menu-icon-trigger").click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); $(".container").toggleClass("container-resize");});
$("#menu-icon-trigger").click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");});
```

When the browser window is wide enough that the sidebar can be visible without overlapping the container, the container does not need to be reduced further. What I want to do, is make it where the container will reduce width *only* when it is being covered up by the sidebar, and not just because the sidebar is visible.

Seems to me that it would work fine if it just subtracted the width of the sidebar (when it is toggled *on*) to the overall window width that it uses when it performs a media query to know whether the container class should reduce further... but how do I setup this rule/query?

Comment: You need to reproduce your problem in a snippet, using minimal code required. Link bootstrap `.css` and `.js` if necessary and add your custom js in the appropriate panel. When your fiddle works and reproduces the problem, people will come up with solutions.

Comment: I understand the question. But I don't have enough info about your page. Hence, I can't give you code that works, because it depends on elements that you have not provided. All you need to do is copy/paste the structure of your page. Create an empty page with an empty sidebar and make it work here. That's all you need to do. Even if it doesn't work, I'll help you make it work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98856/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-kameron-white).

Comment: Here's a live example: 
http://www.sonicproject.com/w2p

Comment: We are currently creating a fiddle as well. Will be editing the question with an answer (hopefully) shortly. thank you for your patience everyone.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense - "the container will reduce width only when it is being covered up by the sidebar". By definition, if the container is 'covered' its width would NOT change. I've tried to interpret what I *think* you wanted in my answer.

Comment: yes you understood correctly, and your answer is appreciated.  It should reduce width only if it were to be covered up otherwise. So rather than being covered, it would reduce width. Thanks for your excellent response!

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to what you are asking - how to dynamically calculate the size of a variable container after accounting for the sidebar - would be to use [CSS calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), like this:

```
// Container is 100% of the viewport minus 250px (width of sidebar)
width: calc(100% - 250px);
```

That gives you a full width container at any resolution, minus the sidebar. I went a step further and tried to finish out an interface ([DEMO on Codepen](http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/dGOMYO), based on a [startbootstrap.com example](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/)).

Above tablet sizes (768px):

- the right sidebar is toggle-able
- the main container is responsive to expanding sidebar (using calc)
- transitions are smooth

Below tablet sizes 768px:

- the right sidebar is fixed open but can get toggled away
- the main container remains fully 100% width at all times
- main container is overlapped by sidebar at all times
- transitions are smooth

Key part to this code is how the `#page-content-wrapper` works with `calc` when the `#wrapper-toggled` class is dynamically applied via JS.

```
#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
  }
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, that's basically what i figured out.. that I wanted a rule that used a calculation like what you wrote: **width: calc (100% - 250px)**.  We set up a fiddle that worked using a very similar rule but instead of using the percent sign, it used the vw unit, like so **width: calc(100vw-250px)** but for some reason, it worked in the fiddle but not on the live site.  So, anyway I decided that it just made more sense to make the sidebar **25vw** and the container **75vw** and that seemed to do the trick without having to use any calc feature, so I guess that's my solution for now.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Do some testing on the `vw` units as they have inconsistent support in older versions of IE and might not be universal solutions (but `calc` has compatibility issues as well). CSS is always a crapshoot.